How do I define an alias/variable in LaTeX which is evaluated before compilation such that its value can be used by other packages?
Please excuse my amateur understanding and nomenclature, I have no formal education about these things. My problem is the following:
I am producing Feynman diagrams using the feynmf package and want to make my lines/propagators coloured. However the feynmf package only allows color arguments of the form (r,, g,, b) and does not accept colors defined e.g. by the xcolor package. I would like to define a variable \mycolor which evaluates already on the code level to an rgb triplet such that the feynmf command will accept it / not even notice I did in fact not write a triplet explicitly. So I do not just want it to evaluate to this triplet upon compilation and pdf rendering, which is what \newcommand, \let and \def apparently do.
I have tried \newtoks\mycolor \mycolor{the triplet} and evaluate it with \the\mycolor as the argument for the feynmf function, but this also does not work.
Is defining variables like this even possible in LaTeX?
Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\newtoks\myblue
\myblue={(0.231,, 0.498,, 0.729)}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{example}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(10,10)
        \fmfleft{i}
        \fmfright{o}
        \fmf{plain,f=\the\myblue}{i,o}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code you have so far? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

I added one for you.

You can define your own colors in metapost, and add them to the .mp file by means of \fmfcmd:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{example}
\fmfcmd{rgbcolor myblue; myblue:=(0.231,0.498,0.729);}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(10,10)
        \fmfleft{i}
        \fmfright{o}
        \fmf{plain,f=myblue}{i,o}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}



Thank you very much! This solves my immediate problem. Also, thanks for polishing my question. However, I would still be interested in whether there is a possibility to define variables as I described (for future use).

@Rooky It might be possible, but honestly I didn't understand the exact requirement. You can ask a new question referring to this one, but then make please clear what the desired input syntax is.

Well I am asking for the syntax to do it so I can't very well provide it. In essence I would like to be able to do, what was now achieved via the definition of a Metapost color regardless of whether the functionality you gave exists or not. I would like to be able to pass some command a variable which it reads as the variable's downvalue. So I would like to define variables like I do e.g. in python.
